# How to change the "/ month" on a woocommerce subscription product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

thanks for checking out my question! I was wondering if there was a way to change the "/ month" on my subscription product page on woocommerce to something different.

Here is a snippet of what it looks like by default:
[Click for Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Peytd.jpg)

So, for example, by default it shows "From: $34.99/month" and I would like to change it to say "From: $34.99" or "From:$34.99 per whatever".

Here is a better snippet: [Click for Snippet of Entire Product page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5muP.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the filter **woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string_inclusions** to remove the subscription period and length parameters so it doesn't display the subscription string.  Add this code to your functions.php file and it will just output the price of the subscription product without the period or length parameters.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string_inclusions', 'remove_subscription_inclusions', 10, 2);

function remove_subscription_inclusions( $include, $product ) {
    $include['subscription_length'] = '';
    $include['subscription_period'] = '';
    return $include;
}
```